# CSS image replacement not working in MSIE 7 and 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, png, image-replacement

I'm having an issue using the empty span css image replacement technique in IE 7 & 8. My logo (transparent png) is missing. I'm assuming that it has something to do with the negative text-indent? Works in all other browsers flawlessly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<h1 class="logo grid_8"><a href="index.html">The Bandwagon<span></span></a></h1>

.grid_8 {text-indent:-1000em; margin:-30px 10px 0 0;}

.logo .grid_8 a{
position:relative;
display:block;
width: 470px;
height: 150px;
overflow:hidden;}

.grid_8 span {
display:block;
position:relative;
width:470px; 
height:150px;
background:url("../img/TBWlogo.png")no-repeat left top;
z-index:1000;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the missing space before the `no-repeat` breaks IE. Try this:

```
background:url("../img/TBWlogo.png") no-repeat left top;
```

The selector `.logo .grid_8 a` selects an `a` element under a element with the class `grid_8` under the class `logo`. According to your markup I think I think you like to select an `a` element under an element  with both classes (`logo` and `grid_8`).

To select an element with multiple classes you need to remove the spaces here.

```
.logo.grid_8 a {}
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Thank you so much.  You have no idea how much this was driving me crazy.  :)